# MySQL query gone wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

another query gone wrong!

I am trying to `INSERT INTO anretOrders (order, orderNumber) VALUES ('test', 15)`

Now, the anretOrders table has 3 columns, but one is the id so i am leaving that out since it auto-increments. The other is "order" which is a text column, and orderNumber which is an int.

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out what is wrong here? what am i missing?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. Should there be anything wrong? (Do you get an error? What does it say)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

escape the field names since `order` is a keyword in mysql

```
INSERT INTO anretOrders (`order`, `orderNumber`) VALUES ('test', 15)
```

Comment: aah i had no idea! Thank you very much! I will accept the answer in 10 min :)

Comment: The why is that `order` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html). You can use reserved words as identifiers, but only if you delimit them like you show.

Comment: @Seerex  it's a general good practice to always use backticks (`) to enclose column names. thought better is avoid a keyword as column name

Answer (score 0):

`order` is a [**Reserved Words**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)

So try like this

```
create table anretOrders (`order` varchar(20),orderNumber int);

INSERT INTO anretOrders (`order`, `orderNumber`) VALUES ('test', 15)
```

[**Sql FIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df795a)